# npm does not add alias automatically when installing a new package

Tags: linux, bash, npm

When I try to run a command to call a package already installed using npm.

e.g: cordova

> cordova -v

It does not work, it works only when I run the full path:

> /Users/James/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -v

For that I need to create an alias for each package in order to avoid calling using the full paths, which causes many issues in many levels.

My npm version is:

> 3.7.3

My O.S

> Mac OSx El Capitan

Answer (score 0):

Add `/Users/James/.npm-packages/bin/` to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-packages/bin/"
```

Add the above to your `~/.bash_profile` and source it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

AFAIK OSX runs bash as a login shell when a terminal is opened, so `.bash_profile` should be used in favor of `.bashrc`.

For more info see: [What is PATH?](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)