# Installing anything through npm doesn't get added to .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, npm

*Edit*
Sorry, I should add that grunt (and other modules I've installed through NPM which aren't working) was installed globally.
*/Edit*

I've only really learned what I currently know about bash this morning so bear with me, this could be a silly question.

Any time I install anything through NPM I'm unable to run the commands. Grunt, for example, gives me this error any time I try to do anything with it "bash: grunt: command not found". I've checked my .bash_profile and it doesn't look like anything is being added to it. I know I can easily add whatever I need to it but before today it's always just worked, I restored my MacBook this morning and it's since then I've had these problems. I installed NVM which got added to the .bash_profile just fine and works without any problems.

Any suggestions or a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: See: [npm does not add alias automatically when installing a new package](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37766113/3776858)

Comment: thanks @Cyrus for the suggestion, doesn't seem to be working for me. The path mentioned in that link doesn't exist in my setup, I only have ~/.npm/(all npm files here). I have two bin files, bin-version & bin-version-check. I added the following to my bash_profile which hasn't made a difference:  export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm"

Comment: To confirm where your global install is located, you can either use `npm -g` and look at the *very* top of the output for the install, OR you can `npm config ls -l` and look for the `prefix` value.  Make sure *that* value is in your $PATH.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBakaitis! Turns out it was a separate issue with NVM that was causing the problems (was set to a default node v which I had uninstalled, PEBKAC error).